# javascript - parameter in a postgres query (e.g. ORDER BY $1) not working properly

Tags: javascript, postgresql, parameters

postgresql / node-postgres / javascript

I am trying to use a parameter $1 in a postrgesql query so I can sort a table based on a string variable (eventually the string variable will come from req.query, but for now it is just a variable called sort that I am creating and defining)

In my code I have:

```
let sort = 'user_name';
const allScores = await pool.query(
            "SELECT * FROM typeTable ORDER BY $1 desc;", [sort]);
console.log(allScores);
```

but allScores does not sort the table by user_name (which is a valid column name)

The code below **does** sort the table by user_name. The only difference is that I am manually writing user_name instead of using a parameter.

```
const allScores = await pool.query(
            "SELECT * FROM typeTable ORDER BY user_name desc;");
console.log(allScores);
```

In my head, I would have thought these two blocks of code would basically be equivalent but they are not. I am not sure what my mistake is. Any help to get the parameter working would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Parameters are for *values*, not identifiers. What you end up with is `SELECT * FROM typeTable ORDER BY 'user_name' desc;`, i.e. you sort by the string literal `'user_name'` which is of course the same for every row and therefore has little effect.

Comment: so there is not a way to dynamically modify an "ORDER BY someColumn" query?

Comment: There may well be, but without information on what database driver you are using it will be difficult to say one way or the other. A generic answer [pg-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-format)

Comment: apologies, I am using node-postgres

Comment: So follow the link I posted.